# Send mail task throwing error

Tags: ssis

I have developed SSIS package where in I have added Send mail task in Event handler. I have also enabled Logging and sending that log file from mail if package fails.I have written expression for creation of log file and also in File attachment property of Send mail task.Upon executing, my log file is getting successfully created but it is not getting attached in send mail task and throwing error that " File does not exist or you do not have permissnio to access it." I also have set 'Delay Validation' property to true. When I tried with some other file (without expression) at same path it is working properly.

Comment: Maybe it's an order of operations issue; the sendmail is happening before the log file is created?

Comment: If this is not working then is there any way to achieve this ??

Comment: Maybe instead of attaching the file to the email, you could include the UNC address of the file in the email body?